# can api be called repetitively from react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am new to react. Could someone help me out on how an api call can be made repetitively every 15mins and the data be rendered onto the application? Please find the code below. I think using setInterval/setTimeout could be an option. But, which one is best and please help me out for my code below. Thanks in advance!

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class UserList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        users: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
            .then(res => {
                const users = res.data;
                this.setState({users});
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.users.map(user => <li>{user.name}</li>)}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use any 1 of them and it should work but just curious, why you wanna make the request every 15 min(s). Is your requirement ask to show live data ? if yes then I guess you can go with `setInterval` or else simply introduce a refresh button and make the call when required.

Comment: Both works but since your are trying to run something at an interval, I would say go with `setInterval`. It's that it was meant for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any 1 of them and it should work but just curious, why you wanna make the request every 15 min(s). Is your requirement ask to show live data ? if yes then I guess you can go with `setInterval` as shown below or else simply introduce a refresh button and make the call when required

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const INTERVAL_DURATION = 15 * 1000 * 60;

export default class UserList extends Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._fetchUserInterval = setInterval(this._fetchUsers, INTERVAL_DURATION);
  }

  componentWillUmount() {
    clearInterval(this._fetchUserInterval);
  }

  _fetchUsers = () => {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`).then(res => {
      this.setState({ users: res.data });
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { users } = this.state;

    return (
      <ul>
        {users.map((user, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{user.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setInterval()` function -

```
componentDidMount() {
  setInterval(() => {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
     .then(res => {
        const users = res.data;
        this.setState({users});
      });
  }, (15 * 1000 * 60));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Use `setInterval` and store the intervalId so you can clean up when the component unmounts.

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class UserList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        users: [],
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        // Keep the interval id
        this.intervalId = setInterval(this.getData, 900000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // use intervalId to clear the interval onUnmount
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }

    getData() {
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
            .then(res => {
                const users = res.data;
                this.setState({ users });
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.users.map(user => <li>{user.name}</li>)}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout()` triggers only once, while for repetitive task `setInterval()` is the option.

You can go this way

```
componentDidMount() {
  setInterval(() => {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users.then(res => {
        const users = res.data;
        this.setState({users});
      });
  }, (15 * 1000 * 60));
}
```

Also, as it is a class component you will have to clear all subscriptions in `componentWillUnmount()` or `getDerivedStateFromProps()`.

Extra note: Always use [keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) while iterating in JSX.

```
render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.users.map((user, index) 
                    => <li key={index}>{user.name}</li>)}
            </ul>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both should work but using setInterval will be an easier option.